# What is laŭŝajne in Esperanto?

Tags: meaning

I've heard it a few times already and it confuses me. Is it "apparently according to..."? Or "According to the appearances of..."? I don't get the combined sense of these two words (*laŭ* and *ŝajne*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without context it is difficult to give an answer. Some examples:

*Tio laŭŝajne estas bona demando* → This looks like a good question.

*Laŭŝajne li estis riĉa.* → It looks as if he is rich.

*Laŭŝajne li ne konsentas.* → It looks as if he does not approve.

Comment: I think my problem is: if the author doesn't use "ŝajnas ke" or "ŝajne" (all possible in your examples, as far as I know), but "laŭŝajne" instead, I don't know what meaning "laŭ" adds to the whole thing. Why not use "ŝajne"?

Comment: In my humble opinion it adds nothing. It's all a question of style.

Comment: Well, I would say that the difference is the same that there is between  "as it seems that" and "it seems that".

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to answer this because "we all know what that one means."

- *Bonvolu alsendi la pordiston. Laŭŝajne estas rano en mia bideo.*

--

Ok, more seriously - it means "according to appearance." The thought process seems to be *laŭ ŝajno -> laŭŝajne*. Without the *laŭ* (i.e. just *ŝajne*) it would mean "appearance-wise" which is just about the same thing.

Comment: Tomaso, mi vere amas vin.

Answer (score 1):

Laŭŝajne = apparently = It appears a certain way

From the Tekstaro

> Laŭŝajne, vi eŭropanoj estas saĝaj...